# Connection Time-out when using smtp mail message

Tags: c#, .net, email

So yes, I have looked at every other post and none of them seem too fix my problem, the SMTP server is Google so its never offline, I have tried combinations of port 25 & 465 with SSL enabled but still time-outs... also my email and password a defiantly not too blame.. ive checked them several times ive also tried different header and body text too make sure it wasnt being rejected

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        MailMessage objeto_mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 465;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Timeout = 10000;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("$$$$$$", "$$$$$");
        objeto_mail.From = new MailAddress("$$$$$");
        objeto_mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("$$$$$"));
        objeto_mail.Subject = "Another Data message";
        objeto_mail.Body = "Testing smtp server please work....";
        client.Send(objeto_mail);
        Console.WriteLine("I WORK hoorayyy");
        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Do you have a firewall enabled on your PC?

Comment: only windows defender at the moment so i could test this... i dont think thats too blame.. still ill have a look

Comment: Tried disabling and running program, but still no luck

Comment: sometimes the internet provider disables the ports, so please try the output exe on a an online server

Answer (score 1):

Please read this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2008/06/02/system-net-mail-with-ssl-to-authenticate-against-port-465/

There are two types of SSL authentication: Explicit and Implicit. Unfortunately System.Net.Mail only supports explicit.

I found a resource on implementing a 3rd party library with support for implicit: https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=2 ... looks like they want money...

Found some NuGet packages: nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/SMTP

I have never directly tried using SMTP before, but this is an interesting problem. Hopefully this helps.

You could also try changing outgoing port to 587, this may allow an explicit authentication.

Comment: I tried changing port to 587 and now it ouputs an error of "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication" even though ssl is enabled

Comment: This looks like progress at least... With explicit SMTP authentication the SSL connection would still happen over port 465, but the initial handshake connection would happen over 587/25. Seems like the built in libraries for .net are not very good for SMTP. I have never implemented SMTP into any projects so I'm not an expert... hopefully you can get to the bottom of it... I'm curious though. Gmail does support Implicit SSL, which is over 465 only, however you would need an external library of some kind, which I do not know of.